How to implement Notifications like WhatsApp for an E2EE Chat App built using Flutter?
I'm trying to send a Push Notification like any other messaging platform like WhatsApp, Telegram, etc. The message is supposed to be End-to-End Encrypted, so the encrypted message needs to be decrypted before showing in the notification banner in the mobile app using flutter_local_notifications. But the data messages are not received on iOS when the app is terminated. Only when a notification object with title or body is added in the payload, the message is received on iOS even in background or terminated state. But results in two notification banners for a message.
Read this in FlutterFire GithHub Discussion without success.
Push Notifications (Firebase) are triggered via AWS SNS: Mobile Push-Notifications. Here's the code invoking Push Notification with payload.
const payload = {
  GCM: JSON.stringify({
    data: {
      message: message
    },
    android: {
      priority: "high"
    },
    content_available: true
  }),
};

const params = {
  Message: JSON.stringify(payload),
  TargetArn: ENDPOINT_ARN,
  MessageStructure: 'json',
};

const publishCommand = new PublishCommand(params);

I highly doubt if WhatsApp, Telegram are actually using Push Notifications in their apps but some kind of background-service. But the background processing is still unpredictable on iOS. So what should be the notification solution for a E2EE chat app built using Flutter?

You will need to include a generic payload to be displayed when your app is terminated. When your app is running you can use a notification extension to process the encrypted data and change what is displayed. Don't base what you can do on what WhatsApp can do. It has access to messaging capabilities that are. O longer available to new apps

You will have to upgrade your flutter version for me 3.22.3

You will receive your notification in
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage

But we should be careful of many points

You should not open WebSocket

You should get your messages by making one HTTP request

You should do your work quickly as the IOS system will close your app at any time

this point happened to me: when checked for the internet it closed the app and didn't complete the work

Sometimes the IOS system will block your app when you try many times so it sometimes doesn't work after sending a lot of FCM

please read this comment also about how sometimes the message may not received in ios https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9563#issuecomment-1259318869

this is backend server side
  admin.messaging().send({data,token,android: {priority: 'high',data,}, apns: {
payload: {
  aps: {
    contentAvailable: true,
    mutableContent: true,
    priority: 'high',
  },
},
headers: {
  'apns-push-type': 'background',
  'apns-priority': '5',
  'bundleIdentifier': 'com.example.packageId', // Replace with 
 your app's bundle identifier
},

},
})


